# Can't install TailwindCSS in create react app

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install TailwindCSS in react but got an error in the command `npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init`. It doesn't generate the `tailwind.config.js` file as expected. Please help me, I'm very grateful.

[image: Image of this bug.]

Comment: Does this help? - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2831

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [official documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)?

First: `npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install React

> `npx create-react-app my-app`

2. Install TailwindCSS

> `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

> `npx tailwindcss init -p`

3. Replace these codes in **tailwind.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

4. Add these in **index.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Congratulations** your setup is completed! *Now you can use tailwind classes*

**For production build** `npm run build` CSS classes automatically optimized, removed unused classed! You don't have to set up another plugin.